# Adding classes for items inside wrap

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$(".feed-item .field-content p").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("item" + (i+1));
});
```

This code help me to add classes in paragraph inside this markup:

```
<div class="feed-item">
  <div class="field-content">
    <p>This must be class item1</p>
    <p>This must be class item2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="feed-item">
  <div class="field-content">
    <p>This must be class item1</p>
    <p>This must be class item2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I need that always the count start on number 1. Have I explained well? Now I get this result:

```
<div class="feed-item">
  <div class="field-content">
    <p class="item1">This must be class item1</p>
    <p class="item2">This must be class item2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="feed-item">
  <div class="field-content">
    <p class="item3">This must be class item1</p>
    <p class="item4">This must be class item2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is that I needed (note the difference is in the class associated with the p tags in the second field-content div):

```
<div class="feed-item">
  <div class="field-content">
    <p class="item1">This must be class item1</p>
    <p class="item2">This must be class item2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="feed-item">
  <div class="field-content">
    <p class="item1">This must be class item1</p>
    <p class="item2">This must be class item2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm working on this link: http://jsfiddle.net/bosspetta/RJkP5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a function to `addClass` method:

```
$(".feed-item .field-content").each(function() {
    $('p', this).addClass(function(i){
       return "item" + ++i
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wc4P3/